# Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined on 'delete module.exports'

Tags: electron

I installed electron [simple-samples](https://github.com/electron/simple-samples/blob/master/prices/package.json). when I update electron to latest 5.0.0, I got this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at index.html:15
```

this is the line

```
delete module.exports
```

What is this line supposed to do? Why is it no more working in 5.0.0 ?

It is working fine with electron 3.0.2 until 4.1.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by a breaking change in Electron 5.0.

In order to have node integration in your app, you have to specify it in the webPreferences settings like this:

mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    }
  });

Reference:
https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/breaking-changes.md#planned-breaking-api-changes-50

Kind regards,
Tailor